# Minimum balance for stake account

Tags: web3.js, staking

I want to split staking accounts, but before I should check minimum balance of stake accounts.
What is minimum balance for staking accounts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the size of the account.

Look at the command `solana rent "your account size"`

For example, an account that stores only its seed and a pubkey (8 + 1 + 32), will cost 0.00117624 SOL.

`solana rent 41`  -->  0.00117624 (Rent-exempt minimum)

Answer (score 1):

Stake accounts are size 200, so their rent exemption is 0.00228288 SOL:

```
$ solana rent 200
Rent per byte-year: 0.00000348 SOL
Rent per epoch: 0.00000625 SOL
Rent-exempt minimum: 0.00228288 SOL
```

The stake state size is also defined at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/45291a50018e218ed85873b33f130aa813bbee08/sdk/program/src/stake/state.rs#L77